# Watering plants with soaked forest soil

Tags: plant-physiology, nutrition, soil

I am thinking of mixing forest soil with water and water plants with that.

I was hoping that nutrients from soil would get released into the water, so in effect, fertilize the soil.

I am not sure if this works, since I am not aware in what chemicals P, K, Ca, Mg is "stored" in forest soil. If it is oxides that it should dissolve rapidly.

So, overall, is it beneficial to the plant to water them with water in which forest soil was dispersed?

Plant in question are tomatoes, peppers.

Comment: So basically you are trying to make your own liquid fertilizer. You might want to search DIY liquid fertilizer, compost sources are common. A small amount of soil is not going to contain much in the way of nutrients. I also recommend reading up on fertilizing practices and nutrient requirements of the plants in question as fertilizer burn is a real thing and if you are seeking multiple sources of fertilizer you can over do it.

Comment: forest soil can be very acidic indeed, its good  for alkaline/clay soils. pond/river silt and dung is much favored. typically place fist of dung beside plant roots to feed them, else mix in 1/4-1/3rd mammal dung depending on its strength/check multiple forest soil pots with tomatoes to see best dose results after 2-3 warm weeks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a better fit for [Gardening.SE](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You are thinking about something like "compost tea".
http://www.homecompostingmadeeasy.com/composttea.html

The problem is that a random piece of forest soil may or may not be rich in nutrients.  If that soil has water soluble nutrients in it, wouldn't the rain have already rinsed them out?

If you make tea out of compost, there has been no chance for rain to rinse out nutrients because the decomposed stuff has been in your compost bin.

Last piece: if you are making tea out of forest soil or compost, when you are done you will have a soaked clump of wet soil or compost.  What are you going to do with it?  Probably throw it on the ground somewhere.  It might make more sense and be much less messy to skip the tea step, put the forest soil or compost on the ground next to your plants, and then water them.